# Adding combo boxes in a particular column of a table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I need to add combo boxes in front of every item in a table for providing feedback. It contains three fields associated with it which can be given in an array.

The number of combo boxes is not constant, user can provide a count. eg. 6. so there will be 6 rows in the table, 6 combo boxes have to be inserted in the third column in front of each row.

Can this be automated for Word using VBA?

Comment: All I can think of immediately is placing a combobox based on number of rows with values (i).  You would then itterate for each i a position offset by the row height.  Essentially it creates i amount of comboboxes, then it distributes them to an offset-location.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. can you provide me written code so that I can implement?

Comment: I'd have to try to build that from scratch.  Start by recording a macro of adding a couple comboboxes, positioning them, then stop recording and step-into the recording.  That's where I would start for this, as well.

Comment: Is there any way to select all shapes (combo boxes) in a word document and name them according to our choice and check that there is a value in every combobox???????

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to a Combobox, the following code adds a validation List (Combobox type).

You need to select a cell next to a Table then pick an item in  this range $D$14:$D$17

Excel will style the column. If you insert a row within the table range, Excel will add that pick list automatically.

```
Sub AddListNexttoTable()
Dim ColumnNexttoTable As Integer
Dim FstRowofTable As Integer
Dim NbRowsinTable As Integer

ColumnNexttoTable = Application.Range("My3ColumnTable").Columns.Count + Application.Range("My3ColumnTable").Column

FstRowofTable = Application.Range("My3ColumnTable").Row
NbRowsinTable = Application.Range("My3ColumnTable").Rows.Count

'Select the cell next to the table and on top
Application.Cells(FstRowofTable, ColumnNexttoTable).Select

'Create a Validation List
AddValidationList

CopyValidationList

End Sub



Sub AddValidationList()

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$D$14:$D$17"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = "Select"
        .ErrorTitle = "Oups!"
        .InputMessage = "Yo Man"
        .ErrorMessage = "Pick Data From the List"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True

    End With

End Sub


Sub CopyValidationList()
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D12"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D2:D12").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Select
    Range("D1").Select
End Sub
```

Here the image after macro execution

[image]

Here the image after user first selection.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Actually I need this in Microsft Word.

Comment: Is there any way to select all shapes (combo boxes) in a word document and name them according to our choice and check that there is a value in every combobox???????

Comment: Combo boxes are Content controls Objet in word. You can only change the “Title” property or “Tag” property. There is no “name” properties. Also the Id properties must be unique. You can select the shapes by using the “Type” properties.
 Here the Microsoft Reference as starting points. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192425.aspx

Here the Microsoft Reference for the “Type” properties
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192401.aspx

Comment: I went through these links..A scenario in which I have inserted 9 combo boxes in the word document..I want to initialize every combo box with three values and I want to check that all the combo boxes should be selected for one value..can u help me with this???

Comment: OK. As a challenge, I will try. It's going to be my first vba on words. Question, all combo box  will have same values or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for Microsoft word.
    It does
     1. Create the combo box in memory (using the cut method)
     2. Create the survey table
     3. Select the third column
     4. Paste the combobox
     5. Update the Last Combobox

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeSurveyTable()

CutCCcbxSurvey CreateCCcbxSurvey

AddSurveyTable

PastecbxSurveytoTableColumn

UdateCombobox4

End Sub

Sub CutCCcbxSurvey(myCCcbxIndex As Integer)

    ActiveDocument.ContentControls(myCCcbxIndex).Cut

End Sub

Function CreateCCcbxSurvey() As Integer

Dim CCcollection As ContentControls
Dim CCcbxSurvey As ContentControl
Set CCcollection = ActiveDocument.ContentControls
Set CCcbxSurvey = CCcollection.Add(wdContentControlComboBox)

With CCcbxSurvey
    .Title = "Survey"
    .Tag = "Survey1"
    .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Please select a response."
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Response 1"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Response 2"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Response 3"
  End With
  CreateCCcbxSurvey = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count

End Function

Sub AddSurveyTable()

ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
NumRows:=4, NumColumns:=3, _
defaulttablebehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

With Selection.Tables(1)

    .Title = "Survey"

End With

End Sub

Sub PastecbxSurveytoTableColumn()

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3).Select
Selection.Paste

End Sub


Sub UdateCombobox4()
'

'
Dim cbxCCSurvey As ContentControl

    Set cbxCCSurvey = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(4)

    With cbxCCSurvey
        .Title = "Favorite Animal"
        .SetPlaceholderText _
        Text:="Please select your favorite animal "

        'List entries
        .DropdownListEntries.Clear
        .DropdownListEntries.Add "Cat"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add "Dog"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add "Horse"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add "Monkey"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add "Snake"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add "Other"
      End With
End Sub
```

Here the result
[image]